# AttributeError while using tk.Entry widget - either grid() or focus_set()

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tk.Entry widget, that I need to have `focus_set()` on, and also need the function `grid()`. Here's the piece of code:

```
e = Entry(...).focus_set()
e.grid(columnspan=3)
```

But the interpreter gives this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    e.grid(columnspan=3)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'
```

Also, if I try to put all the functions in one line it gives same error for the function that goes after first (error for `grid()` if `Entry(...).focus_set().grid(...)` and same in reverse). What do I do?

Comment: It's not the IDE giving you the error, it's the Python interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`focus_set()` does not return the `Entry` itself, but `None`, so you simply said can't chain the calls like that.

Instead, just call them separately.

```
e = Entry(...)
e.focus_set()
e.grid(columnspan=3)
```